# Edit the values returned from an SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql

For a project I am working on I have this OwnershipRole record:

```
public record OwnershipRole
{

    public OwnershipRole()
    {

    }

    public OwnershipRole(Guid id, string title, bool isWithdrawn)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        IsWithdrawn = isWithdrawn;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsWithdrawn { get; set; }
}
}
```

For getting these details I am using an sql query like so:

```
    public List<OwnershipRole> GetOwnershipRoles()
    {

        var sql = @"
SELECT ItemID, Title, Status
FROM ItemDetail";


        var data = GetTable(sql);

        return data.Select().Select(dr => new OwnershipRole
        {
            Id = dr.Field<Guid>(0),
            Title = dr.Field<string>(1),
            IsWithdrawn = !dr.Field<bool>(2)
        }).ToList();
    }

    private DataTable GetTable(string sql)
    {
        var rv = new DataTable();
        using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        cnn.Open();

        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(rv);
    
        cnn.Close();
        return rv;
    }
```

We are grabbing the results and putting them into a data table. The issue I am having however is that the values from the column Status are actually strings. So I am wondering is it possible have a condition of something like:

```
if (Status == "Withdrawn") {
Status == false

}
```

I know that won't work but is there a way I can manipulate the values that I get from the Status column in order to fit in with the bool parameter in the OwnershipRole class?

Comment: What is the datatype of the Status column in your database?

Comment: Side note: `cnn.Close();` is redundant, `using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);` will close `cnn` for you

Comment: The `GetTable()` method really scares me. It practically forces you to write code that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `cnn.Open()` is redundant, too, since `SqlAdapter.Fill()` will also open and close the connection.

Comment: How would you improve it? This was what I have been given and just tasked to expand upon it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, either:

```
        var sql = @"
SELECT ItemID, Title, CASE WHEN Status='Withdrawn' then 1 else 0 end IsWithdrawn
FROM ItemDetail";
```

or

```
    return data.Select().Select(dr => new OwnershipRole
    {
        Id = dr.Field<Guid>(0),
        Title = dr.Field<string>(1),
        IsWithdrawn = dr.Field<string>(2)=="Withdrawn"?true:false
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: There's no need in ternary opertor: `IsWithdrawn = dr.Field<string>(2) != "Withdrawn"`

Comment: That works really well, thank you for that. Knew it would be something simple but just couldn't figure it out, thank you :)

Comment: `data.Cast<DataRow>()` is more efficient, because it doesn't create a new array

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can well read `string` from RDBS and then have `bool` `Status` from it (let get rid of `GetTable` method):

```
  public List<OwnershipRole> GetOwnershipRoles() {
    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    cnn.Open();

    string sql =
      @"SELECT ItemID, 
               Title, 
               Status
          FROM ItemDetail";

    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

    var result = new List<OwnershipRole>(); 

    using var reader = cmd.OpenReader();

    while (reader.Read()) { 
      result.Add(new OwnershipRole(
        Guid.Parse(Convert.ToString(reader[0])),
        Convert.ToString(reader[1]),
        Convert.ToString(reader[2]) != "Withdrawn" 
      )); 
    }

    return result; 
  }
```

Here in the line

```
 Convert.ToString(reader[2]) != "Withdrawn"
```

we read the last field (`Status`) as a `string` which we then convert to `bool` by comparing to `"Withdrawn"`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> The GetTable() method really scares me. It practically forces you to write code that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection.

> How would you improve it?

I'd do something like this:

```
private DataTable GetTable(string sql, SqlParameter[] paras = null)
{
    var rv = new DataTable();
    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    using var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    if (paras != null && paras.Length > 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paras);
    }

    da.Fill(rv);
    return rv;
}

private IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetRows(string sql, SqlParameter[] paras = null)
{
    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    if (paras != null && paras.Length > 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paras);
    }
    cnn.Open();
    using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        yield return rdr;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(string sql, Func<IDataRecord, T> transform, SqlParameter[] paras = null)
{
    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    if (paras != null && paras.Length > 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paras);
    }
    cnn.Open();
    using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        yield return transform(rdr);
    }
}
```

The first method works as-is. You don't even need to use the additional argument for simple queries if there really is no parameters. The other two methods work like this:

```
public IEnumerable<OwnershipRole> GetOwnershipRoles()
{
    var sql = @"
SELECT ItemID, Title, Status
FROM ItemDetail";

    var data = GetRows(sql);
    return data.Select(dr => new OwnershipRole
        {
            Id = (Guid)dr[0],
            Title = (string)dr[1],
            IsWithdrawn = ((string)dr[2])!="Withdrawn"
        });
}
```

And like this:

```
public IEnumerable<OwnershipRole> GetOwnershipRoles()
{
    var sql = @"
SELECT ItemID, Title, Status
FROM ItemDetail";

    return GetItems<OwnershipRole>(sql, row => new OwnershipRole
       {
           Id = (Guid)dr[0],
           Title = (string)dr[1],
           IsWithdrawn = ((string)dr[2])!="Withdrawn"
       });
}
```

Note the return type changes from `List` to `IEnumerable`. A good rule of thumb is the keep things as an `IEnumerable` for as long as possible. This can reduce memory use and set you up to stream values, so in some cases you *never* need the entire result set in memory at all. Soon we'll want to use `IAsyncEnumerable`.

When you do really need a list (which is rarer than you might think), you append the `ToList()` call *after* calling the method. Especially be careful calling `ToList()` on the `GetRows()` function, as it yields the *same object* on each iteration. Doing that wrong can give you a bunch of records all representing the last row.

Finally, if you don't know how to use SqlParameter objects, **STOP** and go Google that, because it's a ***really huge deal***.

Comment: That was a great explanation, yeah I'll definitely look more into this. Thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: I wouldn't return `IEnumerable` if you've already buffered the results in memory.  The caller has to defensively call `.ToList()` which duplicates the collection in case it's a streaming collection encapsulating a DataReader.